# filtering a list of text strings by a list of word strings

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement

i have a list of strings, each consisting out of several words called happenings.
A second list called mostcom20 contains strings which each consist only out of one word.

My goal is to filter out all strings of the first list that do not contain at least one word of the second list.

I have:

```
happenings=["i have a dog","i want a dog","i like cats","i m hungry"]
mostcom20=["dog","cat"]
```

as a results i want a list like:

```
newlist=["i have a dog","i want a dog","i like cats"]
```

This is the code i have:

```
newlist=[]
for s in happenings:
    for n in s.split():
        if n in mostcom20:
            newlist.append(s)
newlist
```

It doesnt give an error message.
It returns an empty list. 
Anyone an idea why? 
Thank you for the help!

Comment: try `print(newlist)` you'll see that it works (well almost since `cat` is not `cats`)

Comment: @PrestonHager huh? `n` is only used in the inner for-loop expression...no?

Comment: Nevermind. I just saw two for loops. My eyes are being weird. That's an `if` statement there! Thanks for pointing that out, forget about what I said earlier about the two for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your program but as a list comprehension. I also renamed the variables so you don't use the same in both loops and changed cat to cats so you get them as well.

```
newlist = [happening for happening in happenings for word in happening.split() if word in mostcom20]
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newlist=[]
for s in happenings:
    for n in s.split():
        if n in mostcom20:
            newlist.append(s)
print(newlist)
```

this is the output

```
['i have a dog', 'i want a dog']
```

if you want in the list also *"i like cats"* you have to add *cats* to common words

Answer (score 0):

You immediate problem seems to be that you aren't printing. You have to `print` explicitely if you want output when running a script, e.g. `python my_script.py`. In an interactive interpreter session, the result of each expression is automatically printed (becuse it is a read-evaluate-print-loop, a REPL). However, there is a logic error in your loop. You need to break out of the inner loop once you find a word that is in the sentence, because if multiple words from your `mostcom20` list are in the sentence, or a singal word appears more than once, then your sentence will be added multiple times. Consider:

```
In [30]: happenings=["i have a dog and a cat","i want a dog","i like cats","i m hungry"]
    ...:
    ...: mostcom20=["dog","cat"]
    ...:

In [31]: newlist=[]
    ...: for s in happenings:
    ...:     for n in s.split():
    ...:         if n in mostcom20:
    ...:             newlist.append(s)
    ...:

In [32]: newlist
Out[32]: ['i have a dog and a cat', 'i have a dog and a cat', 'i want a dog']
```

So remember to `break`:

```
In [33]: newlist=[]
    ...: for s in happenings:
    ...:     for n in s.split():
    ...:         if n in mostcom20:
    ...:             newlist.append(s)
    ...:             break
    ...:

In [34]: newlist
Out[34]: ['i have a dog and a cat', 'i want a dog']
```

You could also use `any` with a generator expression:

```
In [35]: newlist=[]
    ...: for s in happenings:
    ...:     if any(w in mostcom20 for w in s.split()):
    ...:         newlist.append(s)
    ...:

In [36]: newlist
Out[36]: ['i have a dog and a cat', 'i want a dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a short regular expression in conjunction with `filter()`:

```
import re

happenings = ["i have a dog cat dog","i want a dog","i like cats","i m hungry"]
mostcom20 = ["dog","cat"]

rx = re.compile(r'{}'.format('|'.join(mostcom20)))
filtered = list(filter(lambda x: rx.search(x), happenings))
print(filtered)
# ['i have a dog cat dog', 'i want a dog', 'i like cats']
```